# Redux form - sync and submit validation within the same form

Tags: redux, redux-form

I want to use submit and sync validation of a redux form at the same time. Using only one of them at the same time works, but when i'm using both together, it looks like the sync validation is overwriting the results from the submit validation.

```
export default class MyForm extends Component{
    render() {
        ...
        return (
            ...<form>
                  <Button onClick={handleSubmit(submit)}>Submit</Button>
               </form>...
        )
    }
}
```

My submit validation looks like the following:

```
const submit = (values, dispatch) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
        setTimeout(() => {
            reject({ Password: 'Wrong password', _error: 'Login failed'})
            console.log("rejected");
    }, 1000) // simulate server latency
})}
```

Now i'd like to add the sync validation aswell, so i've added `validate` aswell:

```
let myForm = reduxForm({
    ...  
    validate: validateForm
})(MyForm);
```

which looks like the following (stripped to shorten)

```
const validateForm = function(values){
    let errors = {} 
    if(values.Password == "notAllowed"){
        errors.Password = "this is not allowed"
    }

    console.log("validated sync", errors);

    return errors;
}
```

When i now enter something in the password box and hit submit, i can see something like the following:

- "validated sync", ...
- *(hitting submit)*
- *(a second later):* rejected*
- *(immediately after that):* validated sync.

I can see the errors from the sync validation, but not the errors from the submit validation (apparently because it's overwritten by the console output from above). Is there any way to combine those two? I'd like to have live validation *and* server-side verification.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of sync validation is to show *immediate* problems. The purpose of submit validation is to show problems that only can be discovered on the server, e.g. "Record already exists". As such, **sync errors are prioritized before submit errors**. i.e. If your `password` field has both a sync and a submit validation error, the error that Redux Form gives you will be the sync one.

Also, **Redux Form runs sync validation on every render**. So don't get worried about seeing console printouts from your sync validation function.

The thing you are proposing cannot happen, because Redux Form will not submit your form if the sync validation fails. So they really cannot collide. Also, **field-specific submit errors are cleared on `CHANGE`**, so once you go and edit the value, you are going to only ever see sync errors.

Sync and submit validation work happily together. If it looks like they aren't, then you must be doing something wrong, but I cannot determine it from the snippets you posted.

If you really can demonstrate your problem in a JSBin or JSFiddle, that would be great.

Comment: "The thing you are proposing cannot happen, because Redux Form will not submit your form if the sync validation passes." -- Can you mean "if the sync validation fails." @erik-r ?

Comment: Yes. It will not call your submit function if sync validation fails.

Comment: @ErikR. I am experiencing the same issue. There's a signup form, which may lead to a generic server error, which I'd like to set to the _error field. _error gets overwritten after submit, what would be the best strategy to retain this error?